# Attempting to use Microsoft Graph API without POST for bearer token

Tags: python, oauth, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I currently am using the Microsoft Office 365 API to get information about Mailbox Usage and Activity. I am attempting to switch over to the Graph API, and am having some trouble.

When I use the current API, I give an 'auth' field in my header so I avoid posting for a bearer token before sending a GET request.

When I attempt the same in the Graph API I get the following error: "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: -2147184105"

After doing some research, I'm unsure if it is even possible to access the Graph API without posting for a bearer token. I would like to access it by still using the authorization credentials in a 'auth' field. Please let me know of any input/help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

If I follow correctly, you're looking to obtain a bearer token without going through a separate "POST" to convert the authorization code into an access (bearer) token? This is supported by the v2 Endpoint (and Microsoft Graph) using the [Implicit Grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit).

I wrote an article on this a while back that might be helpful getting you started - [v2 Endpoint and Implicit Grant](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-implicit-grant/)